# DB2 importing/replacing fields from a file that contains XML

Tags: db2

In two tables I have a column called table1.column_xml and table2.column_xml_2 defined as CLOB(1000000). The fields in the column contain XML formatted information like below

```
column_xml                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<values>                                                                      
 <comment>test test test</comment>
 <rights></rights>                                                            
 <title>TEST MAN</title>                                         
</values>                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is import/or replace any existing values in table2.column_xml_2 with the values from table1.column_xml.

So in simpler terms I want to export the values from column_xml into a file then import/replace into column_xml_2

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just

```
update table2 set column_xml2 = 
(select column_xml from table1 where <predicate clause>) where <predicate clause>;
```

?

With CLOBs you pretty much have to do that. You can only update the entire CLOB. Now if are on DB2 9.1 or higher, you could store these in a field of type XML and then you could attempt to update specific XML elements like how you are hoping to do.